# (python-pptx) How do I create slides where the title of each slide is a string from a list?

Tags: python, python-pptx

So for example, I have this list:

```
titles =  ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Now I want each title to be the title of each slide
so slide 1 = A, slide 2 = B and slide 3 = C.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [official quickstart guide](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html), here's how you can create a presentation, and for each title in the list, add a slide and set its title from the list:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]

titles = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for slidetitle in titles:
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    slide.shapes.title.text = slidetitle

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Or if you want to edit an existing Powerpoint presentation, you can update the slide titles as follows:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')

text_runs = []
titles = ['A', 'B', 'B']
for i,slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
    slide.shapes.title.text = titles[i]
    print(slide.shapes.title.text)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```